# How to get foreign key value from within refereed class

Tags: django, django-models

Say I have a model Foo that needs to refer to a value that can be one of several datatypes. To account for that I have several models for each datatype. Is it possible from within the Foo model to create a getValue method that would return the value from the first value method it can find connected with it?

example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    def getValue(self):
        if self.hasatr('foovalueint'):
            return self.foovalueint
        elif self.hasatr('foovaluestring'):
            return self.foovaluestring
        elif self.hasatr('foovaluedatetime'):
            return self.foovaluedatetime

class FooValueInt(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, on_delete=CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    value = models.IntegerField()

class FooValueString(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, on_delete=CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class FooValueDateTime(models.Model):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, on_delete=CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    value = models.DateTimeField()
```

Or is there a better way to solve this multiple datatype issue?

Comment: Maybe you should check generic relations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: @MikeBr I think generic realtions might be a good solution, but I am not sure I like that it looses its direct connection to the table in the database. The reason is that others in the company will be using the database, and that might cause confusions